# Symfony2 : a parameters.ini file for each bundle

Tags: database, symfony

In my project there are several bundles each uses a different database, so i thought about making something specific for each bundle in order to indicate the parameters needed by each one of them to access the wanted database. Hope someone gives me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the multiple entity manager documentation.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Create as many entity managers as needed, and then map each bundle to an entity manager like this:

```
entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle: ~
```

You can create multiple parameters.yml files and import them like this in your config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters1.yml }
    - { resource: parameters2.yml }
```

Comment: If you do that, each time you do `composer update|install`, it asks for db parameters.